# Alterar cores da escala de um gráfico bolha no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou com dificuldade de criar uma escala de cores para meu gráfico

```
nome<-c("a","b","c","d")

anos<-c(15,8,25,9)
renda<-c(14,5,3,25)
final<-c(30,15,42,12)

tudo<-cbind(nome,anos,renda,final)

tudo<-as.data.frame(tudo)

attach(tudo)
teste<-ggplot(tudo, aes(x=anos, y=renda, size=final)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, aes(colour =final))

teste + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = nome),
                   size = 3,
                   data = tudo,
                   box.padding   = 0.25,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50',
                   show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
```

As minhas perguntas são as seguintes:

1. Gostaria de criar uma escala de cores da variável `final` para que fosse do azul para os menores valores para o vermelho para maiores valores
2. Gostaria também de saber se é possível colocar os títulos sem a caixa ao redor de cada nome
3. Gostaria de saber também se é possível inserir mais valores nas escalas do gráfico no eixo x e no eixo y, colocando para variar de uma em uma unidade
4. Gostaria de saber também porque o gráfico está tirando de ordem os eixos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou começar pela última pergunta:

> Gostaria de saber também porque o gráfico está tirando de ordem os eixos

Apesar do resultado abaixo,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

os eixos não estão com valores fora de ordem. Note que ao rodar a função `str` nos teus dados, todas as tuas colunas estão classificadas como fatores, com exatamente a mesma ordem apresentada no output abaixo:

```
str(tudo)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ nome : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4
 $ anos : Factor w/ 4 levels "15","25","8",..: 1 3 2 4
 $ renda: Factor w/ 4 levels "14","25","3",..: 1 4 3 2
 $ final: Factor w/ 4 levels "12","15","30",..: 3 2 4 1
```

Para remediar isso, crie seu conjunto de dados da seguinte maneira:

```
nome  <- c("a","b","c","d")
anos  <- c(15,8,25,9)
renda <- c(14,5,3,25)
final <- c(30,15,42,12)

tudo  <- data.frame(nome, anos, renda, final)

str(tudo)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ nome : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4
 $ anos : num  15 8 25 9
 $ renda: num  14 5 3 25
 $ final: num  30 15 42 12
```

Agora sim, `anos`, `renda` e `final` estão como variáveis numéricas.

> Gostaria de criar uma escala de cores da variável final para que fosse do azul para os menores valores para o vermelho para maiores valores

Sim, com `scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")`. Basta informar a cor dos valores baixos (`low`) e dos valores altos (`high`).

> Gostaria também de saber se é possível colocar os títulos sem a caixa ao redor de cada nome

Sim. Use `geom_text_repel` em vez de `geom_label_repel`.

> Gostaria de saber também se é possível inserir mais valores nas escalas do gráfico no eixo x e no eixo y, colocando para variar de uma em uma unidade

Sim. Use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(8, 25, 1))`. Com isso, informamos ao `ggplot2` que as quebras (`breaks`) do eixo x devem começar em 8, terminar em 25 e aumentar de 1 em 1. De modo análogo, `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 25, 1))` resolve o problema para o eixo y.

Juntando tudo num gráfico só, temos o seguinte:

```
nome<-c("a","b","c","d")
anos<-c(15,8,25,9)
renda<-c(14,5,3,25)
final<-c(30,15,42,12)

tudo <- data.frame(nome,anos,renda,final)

teste <- ggplot(tudo, aes(x=anos, y=renda, size=final)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, aes(colour = final))

teste + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = nome),
                   size = 3,
                   data = tudo,
                   box.padding   = 0.25,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = 'grey50',
                   show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(8, 25, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 25, 1)) +
  scale_size(guide = "none")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função `scale_size(guide = "none")` precisa ser colocado para que a legenda com o tamanho dos pontos não apareça. Se ela for necessária, basta retirar esta função ao final do comando.

Comment: Muito obrigado , resolveu meu problema, só mais uma coisa, como faço para os eixos iniciarem no valor 0 ?

Comment: Use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 1), limits = c(0, 25))` e `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 1), limits = c(0, 25))`.